# HTML email text getting clipped

Tags: css, html-email

I'm working on an HTML email template, and the text in my headline gets clipped in Outlook 2007/2010/2013. Here's the relevant code. Suggestions?

```html
<tr>
<td class="main" style="padding:0px 0 21px 20px;">
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr><br />
<td class="h1" style="font:bold 28px/36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000; padding:0px 0 37px;">
Glad to Meet You.
</td>
</tr>
```

And here's a screenshot of the result.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
<td class="h1" style="font:bold 28px/36px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000; padding:0px 0 37px;">
```

to this:

```
<td class="h1" style="font-weight:bold; font-size: 28px; mso-height-rule: exactly; line-height: 36px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#000; padding:0px 0 37px;">
```

Outlook 2007/2010/2013 use MS Word as a rendering engine. Yea, it's pretty terrible, and requires a bit of extra `mso-` CSS. Also as a general rule of thumb, it's safest to stay away from shorthand font declarations in email; separating them out is better.

**EDIT** One more thing is to remove the rogue `<br />` in between the `<tr>` and `<td>`; it's an invalid place to put it and Outlook could be interpreting it in an odd fashion.

Comment: Thanks, Ted. I made the change you suggested and it remains clipped in Outlook 2007/2010/2013 when I test via Litmus. My dev tested it in native Outlook versions, and says it renders correctly.

Comment: Perhaps the error is not in the snippet you pasted above, I see no reason that code should produce clipped text in any email client. Do you have [CSS Resets](http://templates.mailchimp.com/development/css/reset-styles/) in place?

I also edited my answer above to remove that extra `<br />`.